# How can I reinsert a row using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

To add the item with the given description I use: `db.session.add(new_item)`.  To delete the item: `db.session.query(Item).filter_by(item_id=new_id).delete()`.  To update some parts of the item: `db.session.query(Item).filter_by(item_id=new_id).update({"status":"1 "})`.

What should I use if I want to edit the item completely, that is, reinsert the data for the same item?

here is the code for the form:

```
        <form class="form" action="{{ url_for('new_item') }}" method="post" role="form" enctype=multipart/form-data>
      {{ form.csrf_token }}
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="item_name">item name:</label>
              <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="item_name">
            </div>
            </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="item_price">item price</label>
              <input name="price" type="number" class="form-control" id="item_price">
            </div>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="photo">Download the photo</label>
              <input type="file" name="file">
              <p class="help-block">Download</p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="item_category">Category:</label>
              <select name="category" class="form-control" id="item_category">
                <option>LEGO</option>
                <option>Игры_и_игрушки</option>
                <option>Малыш</option>
                <option>Школа_и_канцтовары</option>
                <option>Творчество_и_развитие</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="item_description">Description of the item:</label>
        <textarea name="description" class="form-control" id="item_description" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>


    </form>
```

**Here is the route for the form. There are others as well, to update the items and to delete it, but i guess this should be enough**

```
@app.route('/admin_items', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_items():
    form = AddItemForm(request.form)
    available = db.session.query(Item).filter_by(status='1').order_by(Item.name.asc())
    not_available = db.session.query(Item).filter_by(status='0').order_by(Item.name.asc())
    return render_template('admin_items.html',
                            available_items=available,
                            not_available_items=not_available,
                            form=form)

@app.route('/add_item', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_item():
    error = None
    form = AddItemForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename) and form.name.data != "" and form.description.data != "":
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_ITEMS_DEST'], filename))
            new_item = Item(
                filename,
                form.name.data,
                form.description.data,
                form.price.data,
                form.age.data,
                form.particles.data,
                form.category.data,
                '1',
                )
            db.session.add(new_item)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('admin_items'))
        else:
            return render_template('admin_items.html', form=form, error=error)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect(url_for('admin_items'))
```

Comment: I think your question is asking "How can I pre-populate the form shown to the user with the `Item` data, so the user can make changes and update the object" is that right?

Comment: guess that is right, Dooben! So, when the admin is inserted and posted an object, he then should be able to fully modify it. Not only update the status or remove the object completely, but to modify te description, picture attached, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify more elements to the update clause `.update({"status":"1", "colour":"red"})` or you can grab the object from the database and just change it as required:

```
item = db.session.query(Item).get(1) # grab the item with PK #1.
item.status = '1'
item.colour = 'red'
db.session.commit() # commit your changes to the database.
```

Comment: It is understood, but what if i want to reinsert the data completely? or maybe just put a semicolon somewhere in the sentence of the "description" of the "item". I do not want to do it manually through the flask app.py, instead, i want to do it through admin panel. This is the issue!!!

Comment: Anatoliy-- what is the admin panel you mention?  Is it something you've built?  Is your question really about how to handle form data?

Comment: Unfortunately i am not good at programming and terminology and this is not good that i have asked the qestion not providing enough details :(

Yep, there is an admin panel, which allows admin to write, update and delete posts. However as i have describe, my update function changes only one variable and fully, BUT i want to change manually and not only one variable but, for example, the whole post. Edit it completely. Sorry if  the question is not really clear.

Comment: If your problem is with the form handling part of your code the same update process applies, you grab the existing object in the database, then update each attribute with the data from a field in the submitted form.  If you're using something like flask-wtf, it has a method that can autopopulate models for you, but since you're just starting-- it's probably best to do it the more verbose way to begin.  You'd need to include your form handling code, and the form too for us to see what's happening.

Comment: Sure! I will in a minute!